# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar las etiquetas sólo en el eje X en un gráfico ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

He hecho el siguiente gráfico, sin embargo en las etiquetas del eje X me gustaría que las etiquetas tuviesen un salto de linea sin necesidad de modificar el vector donde se almacena el texto de las etiquetas, pues es un factor y nada mas quiero el salto en el eje X pero no en la referencia de colores. Existe alguna forma de realizar esto?

Código fuente:

```
> vnp <- 100
> vp <- 100 * 1.87
> d <- 65
> c <- d * 0.60
> cr <- 15 * 0.60
> ven_sp <- vnp * d
> gan_sp <- (vnp * d) - (vnp * c)
> ven_p <- vp * d
> gan_s <- (vp * d) - ((vp * c) + (vp * cr)) 
> exp <- c("Ventas sin promocion","Ganancias sin promocion","Ventas con promocion", "Ganancias con promocion")
> ex <- factor(exp, levels = exp)
> df <- data.frame(exp = ex, d = c(ven_sp, gan_sp, ven_p, gan_s))
> p <- df %>% ggplot(aes(exp,d,fill = exp)) + 
+ geom_col()
> p <- p + ggtitle("Simulacion de ventas") + xlab("Escenario") + ylab("Valores en USD")
> p <- p + scale_fill_discrete(name = "Referencia")
> p +  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 50, hjust = 1))
```

He agregado de esa forma las capas de ggplot2 para poder ir probando y luego las he dejado, es por eso que no he creado el gráfico en una sola declaración de p.

[image: Grafico]

Answer (score 2):

Sería algo así, aunque se modifica el vector de texto y se agrega otro

```
 vnp <- 100
 vp <- 100 * 1.87
 d <- 65
 c <- d * 0.60
 cr <- 15 * 0.60
 ven_sp <- vnp * d
 gan_sp <- (vnp * d) - (vnp * c)
 ven_p <- vp * d
 gan_s <- (vp * d) - ((vp * c) + (vp * cr)) 
 exp <- c("Ventas\n sin promocion","Ganancias\n sin promocion","Ventas\n con promocion", "Ganancias\n con promocion")
 exp2 <- c("Ventas sin promocion","Ganancias sin promocion","Ventas con promocion", "Ganancias con promocion")
 ex <- factor(exp, levels = exp)
 df <- data.frame(exp = ex, d = c(ven_sp, gan_sp, ven_p, gan_s))
 p <- ggplot(df,aes(exp,d,fill = exp)) + 
      geom_col()
 p <- p + ggtitle("Simulacion de ventas") + xlab("Escenario") + ylab("Valores en USD")
 p <- p + scale_fill_discrete(name = "Referencia",
                              labels=exp2)
 p +  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 50, hjust = 1))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]